# Ethernet cable is plugged but shows unavailable

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

Here are my logs:

> nmcli device status

[image]

> ```
> ip a
> ```

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:db:f2:39:c8:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:53:30:c4:e6:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.73/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 86340sec preferred_lft 86340sec
    inet6 2400:1a00:b080:451e:8da4:a9dd:1390:b015/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 1146sec preferred_lft 1146sec
    inet6 2400:1a00:b080:451e:f7c1:d4a5:32e7:7cf2/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1146sec preferred_lft 1146sec
    inet6 2400:1a00:b080:451e:aa3c:416c:4b0e:a268/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 1145sec preferred_lft 1145sec
    inet6 2400:1a00:b080:451e:b48c:2c03:13b:707d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1145sec preferred_lft 1145sec
    inet6 fe80::bde9:f641:b23a:2408/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::41d9:1087:9198:178c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

> /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It claims *No carrier*. Are you certain that you have link? Can you try with a different cable?

Comment: the very cable works good in another computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it got resolved by reinstalling network manager, thnx